# Aparent Bug in batoo JPA Map Collection

Tags: java, jpa, dictionary, batoo

I am trying out Batoo for JPA, and in creating a map with the code below:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "BOOLEAN_CONDITION_MAP")
@MapKeyColumn(name = "CONDITION_KEY")
@Column(name = "CONDITION_VALUE")
private Map<String, Boolean> booleanConditionMap = new HashMap<>();
```

However, once a persisted entity is fetched it will only return one entity per unique Value. if i change the Provider to Hibernate it works.

has anyone encountered this before?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated further and removing the FetchType=EAGER fixes this.
I have submitted this as a bug to batoo and will comment if this gets fixed.